# How can I get my Mac to see and transfer files from my android phone?

Tags: mac, android

When I hook up a USB cable from my Mac to my Samsung Galaxy phone I get a notice that says
"Can't access device storage" "Make sure your device is unlocked and that File transfer or MTP mode is selected"
How do I find "MTP mode"? How do I find "Unlock"?

Answer (score 2):

Android devices require a driver/app install - they will not natively hook up to a Mac.

Google provides [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) for this task.

Comment: A few months before iPhone 10 came out my previous iPhone died, so I use an Android for for a few months until the iPhone 10 was available. I tried using Android File Transfer and it was worthless, just kept crashing. Had to take the SIM out of the phone and access it through a card reader to manually sift through and transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using samsung galaxy s10 and they seem to have an app for transferring: [Samsung smart switch](https://www.samsung.com/us/apps/smart-switch/). Roll down to the bottom of the page to get the macOS version. During or after installing you need to go to "Security&Privacy" in macbook "setting", on the page "general", unlock first, and then you will see the button shows up at the bottom. Get into there, tick "smart-switch" and click ok. Now you installed the app.

Then open the app on your macbook. Connect to your phone with a cable and then you can move as many as files as possible. It worked great.

Took me some time to figure this out!